# Key and value must be in retrofit Header

Tags: java, header, key, token, retrofit2

I made an application using Retrofit, but there is a problem without the token does not work. Must use Key and Value (Token). I understand that it is necessary to do it with the help of Header, but how?

```
@Headers("Authorization")
@GET("api/Profiles/GetProfile?id={id}")
Call<ResponseData> getUser(@Header("X-Lisa-Lanet") token, String);
```